# mandar dado json do ajax para o php

Tags: php, ajax, json, array

Arquivo JS:

```
var jsonsave = [];

var dado = new Object();
dado.nome= "João";
dado.cpf = "000";
dado.teste = "teste";
var jason = JSON.stringify(dado);
jsonsave.push(jason);


$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "JSON",
               url: "http://localhost/moodle/my/index.php",
               data: "data="+jsonsave+"&ENVIO_RESPOSTAS=true",
               success: function(data){
                   console.log('foi');
               },
               error: function(data)
               {
                    console.log(data);

               }
           });
```

Arquivo php:

```
$arquivo = $_POST['data'];
$value= json_decode($arquivo, TRUE);
```

Eu chamo a página php pelo ajax, porém não consigo pegar os valores do json, vem null, alguem tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Vi agora que você já tinha postado essa pergunta a pouco. E postou novamente. Não é recomendável fazer isso. Sua pergunta será respondida assim que alguém com conhecimento no assunto e com disponibilidade de tempo, visualizar ela. Postar a mesma pergunta novamente, só vai fazer com que ela seja excluída.

Comment: ah eu exclui aquela, porque eu ja tinha postado, achei que não tinha ido, foi eu mesmo que exclui aquela, desculpe

Comment: Ok, nesse caso, desconsidere o que eu disse.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta enviar os dados no formato JSON puro:

```
 ...
 dataType:"json",
 url: "http://localhost/moodle/my/index.php",
 data: jason, 
 ...
```

E no PHP, para obter os valores:

```
$json = json_encode($_POST);
var_dump($json);
```

**Observação:**

Para que você consiga checar se o PHP recebeu os dados, você deve mostrar o retorno no terminal, ou de alguma outra forma. Pois fiz um teste e constatei que mesmo da forma que está fazendo, o PHP recebeu os dados. Então recomendo a seguinte alteração para poder checar isso:

```
 success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
 },
```

Resposta obtida ao executar essa alteração no código que você forneceu:

```
//string(62) ""{\"nome\":\"Jo\u00e3o\",\"cpf\":\"000\",\"teste\":\"teste  //\"}""
```

Ter os dados nesse formato, no PHP, não faz muito sentido, talvez o que você queira é obter um `array`/`object`. Nesse caso, está utilizando a função inversa. O correto seria `json_decode`:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['data']);
var_dump($json);
```

E a saída:

```
//object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
//  ["nome"]=>
//  string(5) "João"
//  ["cpf"]=>
//  string(3) "000"
//  ["teste"]=>
//  string(5) "teste"
//}
```

Comment: não deu certo mesmo assim

Comment: vou fazer um teste, ver o que está ocorrendo então.

Comment: eu preciso manter o ENVIO_RESPOSTAS também no caso

Comment: Teu código está funcionado, assim como a forma que sugeri. Tem certeza que está checando da forma correta? Da uma olhada na edição da resposta.

Comment: eu alterei para:
    type: "POST",
                   dataType:"JSON",
                   url: "http://localhost/moodle/my/index.php",
                   data: "data="+jsonsave+"&ENVIO_RESPOSTAS=true",
como você sugeriu mas ele cai no error do ajax, se eu tiro o dataType ele vai porém vai nulo

Comment: qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: object {readystate: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}

Comment: "url: "localhost/moodle/my/index.php";, ", o código é esse mesmo? pois tem um ";" onde não deveria.

Comment: não, no codigo ta virgula mesmo, acho que foi edição do site

Comment: Ta retornando null? No seu código original você não estava exibido a resposta do servidor. Apenas a mensagem "foi". Explica melhor isso.

Comment: ele cai no sucess se eu tiro o datatype: "json" , agora se eu coloco vai pro error

<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html  dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lan…29'); });↵})();↵//]]>↵</script>↵↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: edita o código da pergunta, da forma que está fazendo agora.

Comment: alterei la o codigo

Answer (score 0):

Uso muito isto:

```
var PrimeiroNome=$("#InputPrimeiroNome").val();

$.post("pagina2.php",{nome:PrimeiroNome}).done(function(resultado){
   $("div #recebeValor").html(resultado);
});
```

Basicamente dentro do javascript vai abrir uma pagina2.php em segundo plano onde vai enviar o valor da input com o id ="InputPrimeiroNome" atribuilo a um POST para O PHP com o nome de "nome" e vai devolver o echo dessa pagina php e atribuilo a div #recebeValor 
Com algumas brincadeiras assim pode tornar o site bem dinamico

Answer (score -2):

Tente utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
    $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "http://localhost/moodle/my/index.php",
                   data: function (data){
                      data.data = jason;
                      data.envio_resposta= true;
                   },
                   success: function(data){
                       console.log('foi');
                   },
                   error: function(data)
                   {
                        console.log('n foi');

                   }
               });
```

Abraço,

Answer (score -2):

No meu caso deu certo o usado pelo Bruno Almeida:

var PrimeiroNome=$("#InputPrimeiroNome").val();

$.post("pagina2.php",{nome:PrimeiroNome}).done(function(resultado){
   $("div #recebeValor").html(resultado);
});

e no php usei:
$arr = json_decode($_POST['nome']);
echo $arr

Answer (score -3):

Utilizo dessa forma:

```php
$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($postdata);
```